# Is there a tag similar to \textsc (from LaTeX) in HTML?

Tags: html, text, latex

I have not found anything similar to the `\textsc` tag in LaTeX for HTML on Google, so maybe I am mixing something up. How can I represent small caps in HTML with?

Answer (score 1):

You achieve the same affect of small caps (`\textsc`) in HTML with some CSS. The CSS property [`font-variant-caps`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-variant-caps) can do what you want. Per the link:

> The `font-variant-caps` CSS property controls the usage of alternate glyphs for capital letters. Scripts can have capital letter glyphs of different sizes, the normal uppercase glyphs, small capital glyphs, and petite capital glyphs.

There are a few applicable values for what you want:

> #### Values
>
> **`small-caps`**
>
> This keyword forces the use of small capitals letters for lower case characters. It corresponds to the OpenType value `smcp;` if the font doesn't support them, it synthesizes the glyphs.
>
> **`all-small-caps`**
>
> This keyword forces the use of small capital letters for lower case characters. It corresponds to the OpenType values smcp and `c2sc;` if the font doesn't support them, it synthesizes the glyphs.
>
> **`petite-caps`**
>
> This keyword forces the use of petite capital letters for lower case characters. It corresponds to the OpenType value `pcap;` if the font doesn't support them, small caps glyphs are used instead.
>
> **`all-petite-caps`**
>
> This keyword forces the use of petite capital letters for lower case characters. It corresponds to the OpenType values `pcap` and `c2pc;` if the font doesn't support them, small caps glyphs are used instead.

Here's a snippet demonstration:

```css
#small-caps {
  font-variant-caps: small-caps;
}  

#all-small-caps {
  font-variant-caps: all-small-caps;
}  

#petite-caps {
  font-variant-caps: petite-caps;
}  

#all-petite-caps {
  font-variant-caps: all-petite-caps;
}
```

```html
<strong>Using <code>small-caps</code></strong>

<p id="small-caps">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<hr />

<strong>Using <code>all-small-caps</code></strong>

<p id="all-small-caps">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<hr />

<strong>Using <code>petite-caps</code></strong>

<p id="petite-caps">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<hr />

<strong>Using <code>all-petite-caps</code></strong>

<p id="all-petite-caps">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<hr />
```